# How to filter for only .jpg file in browse window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I want to filter the browse window for only .jpg files.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileDocument" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>
```

Here is the image :- [image]

here I want that it should only display .jpg file.
How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521122/html-input-type-file-apply-a-filter possibble duplicate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780191/how-to-restrict-file-type-in-fileupload-control possible duplicate

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:

[File Upload with RegularExpressionValidator not working with Firefox only IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810541/file-upload-with-regularexpressionvalidator-not-working-with-firefox-only-ie)

However I believe exactly what you want to do may not be possible with the library you are using, you could try a different javascript library to do the file select.

Take a look at this:
http://www.queness.com/post/11434/7-javascript-ajax-file-upload-plugins

Answer (score 0):

I used RegularExpressionValidator before.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="validator_fileupload_extension" runat="server"
     ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"
     ErrorMessage="Images are allowed"
     Text="*" 
     ValidationExpression="^.*\.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG)$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this script in the head section of the aspx page.

```
 <script type ="text/javascript">
    var validFilesTypes=["bmp","gif","png","jpg","jpeg","doc","xls"];
    function ValidateFile()
     {
         var file = document.getElementById("<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>");
         var path = file.value;
         var ext=path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".")+1,path.length).toLowerCase();
         var isValidFile = false;
         for (var i=0; i<validFilesTypes.length; i++)
            {
              if (ext==validFilesTypes[i])
                 {
                      break;
                 }
            }
         return isValidFile;
     }
</script>
```