# How to prevent specific extension in asp.net FileUpload Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to provent few extensions to load in FilUpload control. I have review few references

https://forums.asp.net/t/1051895.aspx?Fileupload+allow+only+jpg+gif+and+png

[ASP.NET - Limit file upload available file types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491257/asp-net-limit-file-upload-available-file-types)

But all are related to "which extensions should be allowed". But I need "which extensions should not allowed".

Can anybody please suggest me regular expression or any other way? I don't want to check manually while submiting.

I have read this example which regular expression about which files to allow. But I need ValidationExpression which doesn't allow some extension. I have list of extension which should not allowed. Can anybody suggest me `ValidationExpression` of it?

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="uplValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"
ErrorMessage=".mp3, .mp4 & wma formats are allowed" 
ValidationExpression="(.+\.([Mm][Pp][3])|.+\.([Mm][Pp][4])|.+\.([Ww][Mm][Aa]))"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Write the validate regular expression to disallow the extensions you don't want.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava no. they are not allow. I have just given example. I have opposite situation. I want `ValidationExpression` which doesn't allow .mp3, .mp4 & wma. Can you please guide me?

Comment: Ohk. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11789389/5588347). So in Harish answer, why don't you try something like this: `if (reg.test(uploadcontrol) == true)` ? That's not actually a well solution but still it should work.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava I don't want any manual code(no event like button click). Is there any ValidationExpression that I can set in `RegularExpressionValidator`? If so, please suggest.

Comment: You can try this Validation Expression: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178316/regular-expression-for-excluding-file-types-exe-and-js

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML 5 `accept` attribute.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" accept="video/*" />
```

You can still select all file types, but for most users this will be sufficient. And you still need to check the file type server-side, same as with RegularExpressionValidators.

[Read more](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_input_accept.asp)